# JSP varStatus javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property status is not found on type

Tags: jsp, loops, foreach, jstl

I'm having the problem with get objects from List by index:

My jsp:

```
    <c:choose>      

                <c:when test="${empty findAttributes}">

                    <h1 align="center">Attributes are empty</h1>

                </c:when>

                <c:otherwise>


                    <table  align="center" border="1" id="resultTable">


                            <c:forEach items="${findAttributes}" var="findAttributesVar" varStatus="status"> 

                                    <tr>    

                                    <td align="center">${findAttributesVar.status.index.formDescriptionList.status.status.institutions.nameOfInstitution}</td>

                                    <td align="center">${findAttributesVar.status.index.formDescriptionList.status.status.institutionType.typeOfInstitution}</td>

<td align="center">${findAttributesVar.status.index.formDescriptionList.daySchedule}</td>

                                    <td align="center">${findAttributesVar.status.index.formDescriptionList.workScheduale}</td>

                                    </tr>

                          </c:forEach>                                                                                                      

                    </table>

                </c:otherwise>

            </c:choose>
```

I'm fetching attribute as list `findAttributes` and try to get objects by index in jsp page , similar to java code like:

```
attributesList.get(i).getFormDescriptionList().get(i).getInstitutions().getNameOfInstitution());
attributesList.get(i).getFormDescriptionList().get(i).getInstitutionType().getTypeOfInstitution();
attributesList.get(i).getParticularDate().toString());
attributesList.get(i).getFormDescriptionList().get(i).getDaySchedule());
attributesList.get(i).getFormDescriptionList().get(i).getWorkScheduale());
```

My stack trace error:

```
Jul 26, 2013 4:57:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/web] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/search.jsp at line 141

138:                                <tr>    
139:                                
140:                                <td align="center">${findAttributesVar.particularDate}</td>
141:                                <td align="center">${findAttributesVar.status.index.formDescriptionList.daySchedule}</td>
142:                                <td align="center">${findAttributesVar.status.index.formDescriptionList.workScheduale}</td>
143:                                <td align="center">${findAttributesVar.status.index.formDescriptionList.rotation}</td>
144:                                <td align="center">${findAttributesVar.status.index.formDescriptionList.numberOfKids}</td>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'status' not found on type edu.demidov.dto.FormDate
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:223)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:200)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:311)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.search_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f3(search_jsp.java:1157)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.search_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f0(search_jsp.java:790)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.search_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(search_jsp.java:639)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.search_jsp._jspService(search_jsp.java:222)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My FormDate entity:

package edu.demidov.dto;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FORM_DATE")
public class FormDate implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6727012506326164775L;


    private int dateId;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="DATE_ID")
        public int getDateId() {
            return dateId;
        }   
        public void setDateId(int dateId) {
            this.dateId = dateId;
        }


    private int version;

        @Version
        @Column(name="VERSION")
        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }
        public void setVersion(int version) {
            this.version = version;
        }


    private Date particularDate;

        @Column(name="PARTICULAR_DATE")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        public Date getParticularDate() {
            return particularDate;
        }
        public void setParticularDate(Date particularDate) {
            this.particularDate = particularDate;
        }


    private List<FormDescription> formDescriptionList = new ArrayList<FormDescription>();

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="formDate")
        @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<FormDescription> getFormDescriptionList() {
            return formDescriptionList;
        }
        public void setFormDescriptionList(List<FormDescription> formDescriptionList) {
            this.formDescriptionList = formDescriptionList;
        }

}
```

How it's create table with `c:forEach` nester in `c:forEach` with two objects in Attributes:

```
         -=TABLE=-
|header1|header2|header3|
-------------------------
|value1| Value1 |value1 |
-------------------------
|value2| Value2 |value2 |
-------------------------
|value1| Value1 |value1 |
-------------------------
|value2| Value2 |value2 |
```

Comment: What is the type contained in `List findAttributes` ? Show us the definition of `edu.demidov.dto.FormDate` class .

Comment: I added it to the question post

Comment: So, when you're looking at the fifth FormDate in your list, you only care about the fifth FormDescription it contains? That's quite strange. Don't you want two nested loops instead?

Comment: Sir it just peace of code before it I have For(int=0; i<attributes.size(); i++) and after already those 5 lines of code.

Comment: You didn't get me. You're using the same index to get the current FormDate, and to get the description inside the list of descriptions of this FormDate. I don't think that's what you want. You probably want another loop to display all the descriptions of each FormDate

Comment: Yes Sir you are right I have FormDescription list inside of FormDate. How can I iterate over List of entities where inside of each entity List of FormDescription also entities.? Could you help me also please?

Answer (score 0):

The line of Java code:

```
attributesList.get(i).getFormDescriptionList().get(i).
getInstitutions().getNameOfInstitution());
```

Its JSTL/EL equivalent in your case will be:

```
${findAttributes[status].formDescriptionList[status].institutions.nameOfInstitution}
```

Use the bracket notation for `[status]`.

**Better to use a separate `forEach` loop for the nested `List` .**

```
<c:forEach items="${findAttributes}" var="findAttributesVar">
   <c:forEach items=${findAttributesVar.formDescriptionList} var="formDescription">
      Value : ${formDescription.institutions.nameOfInstitution}
   </c:forEach> 
</c:forEach>
```

Remember all the bean classes you refer here should have public getter methods as per the Java bean spec. and naming conventions. [Read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) for more information on how to use EL.

Comment: Sir. Is this related to "Public getter methods as per the Java bean spec. and naming conventions" that I have javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@70c8bc' not found on type edu.demidov.dto.FormDate ???

Comment: I did how you said. That's why I'm very accurate to ask you again. I put status inside of brackets.

Comment: Sorry , try with `${findAttributesVar.formDescriptionList[status].institutions.nameOfInstitution}` !

Comment: Yes Sir I tried already.. it throws exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@1f36baf  Sir if I will use separate forEach for every list in this case I don't need to use a varStatus, but in this case I will have to get all FormDate entities from attributes and all FormDescription entities from the same list of attributes. The problem maybe in my bad context of question. I have inside of each entities FormDate another list of FormDescription. That why I want to puck up right by index.

Comment: I don't understand the edit in your question. Please provide example input (i.e. what does the list of FormDate contain, and what does the list of descriptions in every of the FormDate contains), and what you **would like** as an output given this input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply want to iterate over a list of `FormDate` instances, and to display each `FormDescription` of each FormDate in the list. So you need a first loop:

${formDate.particularDate}
        here should the list of FormDescription of the current formDate be displayed

You don't need `varStatus` for this loop, just as in Java you just need

```
for (FormDate formDate : findAttributes) {
    System.out.println(formDate.getParticularDate());
    System.out.println("here should the list of FormDescription of the current formDate be displayed");
}
```

without any need for the index of the current iteration.

To display the list of FormDescriptions, you need another loop:

```
for (FormDate formDate : findAttributes) {
    System.out.println(formDate.getParticularDate());
    for (FormDescription description : formDate.getFormDescriptionList()) {
        System.out.println("    " + description.getDaySchedule());
        System.out.println("    " + description.getWorkSchedule());
    }
}
```

Note that once again, you don't need any index. In the JSP, it would look like

```
<c:forEach var="formDate" items="${findAttributes}">
<tr>
    <td>${formDate.particularDate}</td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="description" items="${formDate.formDescriptionList}>
                <li>
                    ${description.daySchedule} - ${description.workSchedule}
                </li>
            </c:forEach>            
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Of course, the layout is up to you. But you should get the idea of how to iterate using `c:forEach`.

Comment: Ok it's totally my bad. I did not make clear question context. Sir, I already for a couple days can not totally make my table render in way I want it to. Sir, I tried it already and this is was my first way how I tried to make it. The problem came up with forEach that it repeat all my data for attributes and add it to the table. If I have 2 Objects in List it render 4 if I have 3 it render 6. This Problem occurs when I have <c:forEach> inside <c:forEach>. And I cant prevent it. I put example in my question. That why I choose to use fetching by index